# React testing library: An update inside a test was not wrapped in act(...) & Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-testing-library

In my test, the component receives its props and sets up the component.

This triggers a useEffect to make an http request (which I mock).

The fetched mocked resp data is returned, but the cleanup function inside the useEffect has already been called (hence the component has unmounted), so I get all these errors.

How do I prevent the component from un-mounting so that the state can be updated? I've tried act, no act, nothing causes the component to wait for the fetch to finish.

I should say my warning are just that, warnings, but I don't like all the red, and it indicates something is going wrong.

```
export const BalanceModule = (props) => { 
  const [report, setReport] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://.....').then((resp) => {
      console.log("data returned!!!")
      setReports((report) => {
        return {...report, data: resp}
      })
    })
    return () => {
     console.log("unmounted!!!")
    }; 
  }, [report])

  .... trigger update on report here
}

// the test:
test("simplified-version", async () => {
  act(() => {
    render(
       <BalanceModule {...reportConfig}></BalanceModule>
    );
  });

  await screen.findByText("2021-01-20T01:04:38");
  expect(screen.getByText("2021-01-20T01:04:38")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
test("simplified-version", async () => {
  act(() => {
    render(<BalanceModule {...reportConfig}></BalanceModule>);
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    screen.findByText("2021-01-20T01:04:38");
    expect(screen.getByText("2021-01-20T01:04:38")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that wrapping everything into an await waitFor(()=>{ }) did the trick, though I don't understand how my await with findByText (findByText also returns a promise) didn't work

Comment: @blomster `waitFor` method use `act` function internally. you could just do what you did, instead wrap it with `act` function